# Other reconciliation services in GraphDB

Tags: openrefine, graphdb, reconcile

I have been looking for reconciliation services with ontorefine in graphDB. In the following link
https://medium.com/wallscope/linked-data-reconciliation-in-graphdb-cd2796d2870b reconciliation is performed with the DBpedia endpoint. I want to reconcile with another endpoint. What are those other endpoints that I could reconcile with? Are they the same ones that OpenRefine uses? like VIAF, wikidata and others. Or can I use any endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

You can add external reconciliation in the OntoRefine. Click on the column you want to reconcile -> Reconcile -> Start reconciling -> Add standart service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any reconciliation server (endpoint) in OntoRefine.
In addition:

- We've developed a VIAF recon server that's much better than previously existing ones. It takes into account name variants, parses out nationality and occupation, and sorts candidates by some "importance" metrics. We have not yet deployed this as we're looking for a client.
- You can implement recon over RDF data, using the same framework that the above VIAF server uses (which is based on mapping RDF props to Lucene/Elastic and using its "similar" functionality). Again, we're looking for a client or pretext to release this framework as part of GraphDB.

OntoRefine is not just a reskinned and rebranded version of OpenRefine, but it adds the ability to render tabular data as RDF (like the obsolete DERI extension):

- either by a mapping UI or SPARQL
- either for download or direct insert (materialization) to GraphDB (using INSERT over internal federation)

Comment: Updated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53377236/setting-up-an-openrefine-reconciliation-endpoint-over-graphdb/55087856#55087856 with the first two bullets

Answer (score 0):

Since it's proprietary and closed source, it's hard to say for sure, but "OntoRefine" appears to be just a reskinned and rebranded version of OpenRefine, so I assume that it can use all the same reconciliation services.

You can find a list of OpenRefine reconciliation services here: https://reconciliation-api.github.io/testbench/

Answer (score 0):

Confirming what Konstantin and Tom wrote, you can use any Reconciliation service with OntoRefine. I've added 3 lists of such services at https://openrefine.org/download.html:

- https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Reconcilable-Data-Sources : maybe a bit older but more descriptive
- https://reconciliation-api.github.io/census/services/ : software
- https://reconciliation-api.github.io/testbench/#/ : online services